# Can I limit who can merge into a branch?

Tags: git, github, merge

Our process involves feature branches, a master branch, and a production branch:

1. All work occurs on a `feature branch`.
2. When ready, a `feature branch` gets merged into `master` via a pull request.
3. When the site is ready to be updated, `master` gets merged into `production`.

I'd like to only allow specific users (our project administrators) to merge `master` into `productions`.

I'd like to only allow the `master` branch to be merged into production.

I'd also like to only allow additions to `master` via pull requests.

I can code, so pointing me towards similar examples, existing tutorials, etc is great!  Using pre-commit or other githooks is an acceptable solution.

Comment: If you have `production` in a separate repository you can limit who is allowed to push to this repository. Would that be enough?

Comment: That's a great thought and certainly works!  In my case I'd say it adds too much complexity and isn't worth it (we'll just stick to manually enforcing these rules).  But if you want to add your suggestion as an answer for others to see I'd happily upvote it.

Comment: Why does this add complexity? I think that writing scripts to check who pushed what changes is more difficult and certainly not bullet proof.

Comment: I see your point, and may end up going with this.  However I'd still like to look into other solutions. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for this is to just tell your team not do it. If anybody still does it, you will easily see that when looking at your history. If you are afraid that they might create commits under your name and push them to production, you should probably not have them coding at all.